# UNIX terminal - shell won't terminate, stuck in for loop

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm having some trouble terminating a shell. I'm starting several filkontroll.sh in the background to regularly check files to see if they have been changed or deleted. It seems to be running fine except that when all the files have been modified, the program won't terminate. It's seems to be stuck in the for-loop somehow.

```
filkontroll.sh :
#!/bin/bash
clear

declare -i status=1
if [ -f $1 ]
        then
        status=0
        timestamp=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%H%M%S" $1)
fi
while [ 0 ]
        do
        if [ -f $1 ] && [ $status -eq 1 ]
                then
                echo "Filen $1 ble opprettet."
                break
        elif [ ! -f $1 ] && [ $status -eq 0 ]
                then
                echo "Filen $1 ble slettet."
                break
        elif [ -f $1 ]
                then
                sistEndret=$(stat -f "%Sm" -t "%H%M%S" $1)
                if [ ! $sistEndret -eq $timestamp ]
                        then
                        echo "Filen $1 ble endret."
                        break
                fi
         fi
        sleep $2
done



kontrollflerefiler.sh:
#!/bin/bash
clear

for fil in $@
do
        . filkontroll.sh $fil 2 &

done
```

Comment: What version of `stat` do you have (that command for the stat I have here doesn't do anything useful)? Are you monitoring files or filesystems?

Comment: The `if` and first `elif` are always false, because `status` is explicitly set to 1 if `$1` does not exist, and set to 0 if it does. So, if `$1` doesn't exist (for example, removed after the associate process starts), the loop never terminates.

Comment: There's a lot wrong with this script that http://shellcheck.net/ will detect and provide line-by-line notes on.

Comment: Etan: I am monitoring files. I don't know what version I have, but I'm using the terminal window on an updated OSX Macbook Air. It returns the last modified timestamp in the format "hhmmss"

Chephner: They are not always false. I have tried all tree cases, and when I run just filkontroll.sh it runs smoothly.

Comment: @chepner This script is a file monitoring script. It is intended to watch for out-of-band file changes. Or so the question would lead me to believe.

Comment: Which script is "getting stuck" `filkontroll.sh` or `kontrollflerefiler.sh`?

Comment: @Etan - yes; my point is, only the last `elif` can ever be true, so the `while` loop only terminates if a file that once existed still does and has changed. It's unclear what the user is experiencing, since the `for` loop will terminate as soon as it starts a background process for each file that originally existed.

Comment: @chepner I don't see why the first two cannot be true if the file is created/deleted outside the script? If the file exists when the script starts then `status=0` and the terminating condition should be `! -f && status -eq 0` (which is contrary to the starting condition of `-f && status -eq 0`). And vice versa for a file that initially does not exist.

Comment: Ah, right. `status` indicates if the file existed originally or not.

Comment: @EtanReisner It appears to be kontrollflerefiler.sh that is stuck. I tried inserting an echo "Sup" to filkontroll.sh, and when all the files have been modified, "Sup" doesn't appear in the terminal.

Comment: That script cannot get stuck in that loop (or really at all). What are you seeing that makes you think something is getting stuck?

Comment: Because the terminal windows doesn't "go back" to its normal state. It's still busy.. I'm sorry, my terminology isn't the best, I just started with bash. I have to press CTRL + C to continue using the terminal.